# Does OpenRC support cgroups v2?

Tags: linux-kernel, cgroups, openrc

A simple question: does OpenRC support cgroups version 2?

It seems that only version 1 is supported. And if it supports v2, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cgroup v2` can be enabled under **OpenRC** by setting in `/etc/rc.conf`:

`rc_cgroup_mode="unified"`

& rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to support cgroups v2 yet

Here's an open issue:
https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc/issues/94

Comment: Might want to update this answer; that issue is closed now.